# Getting 404 Not found when refresh page in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, iis, azure-web-app-service

I'am getting error "404 Not found" when i refresh any page in my Vue JS application hosted in Azure Web APP (IIS Server) except the default web page `index.html`

I'am already adding this rewrite configuration in my `web.config` according to VueJs offical docs :

```js
    <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
```

This is my `web.conf` file:

```js
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                     <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
                       <match url="(.*)" />
                      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                         <add input="{​​​​​​​REQUEST_FILENAME}​​​​​​​" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                         <add input="{​​​​​​​REQUEST_FILENAME}​​​​​​​" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                      </conditions>
                      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                    </rule>
    
    
                    <rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                            <add input="{​​​​​​​REQUEST_FILENAME}​​​​​​​" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                         </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>

the `router.js` file have this conf : 

    const router = new VueRouter({
      mode: 'history',
      routes: [...]
    })
```

Any idea to resolve that ?

Regards

EDIT :

Just ADD `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa` , in

```
Azure Portal > App Service > Configuration > Application Setting
```

Azure APP Service based on Linux , don't need to use web.config

BR.

Comment: You can use failed requests tracing to get the cause of this error: [Troubleshooting Failed Requests Using Tracing in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85).

Comment: Sorry , but i think it's out of scope

Comment: You need to use FRT to get detailed error information.

Comment: change <action type="Rewrite" url="/" /> to <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.htlm" />, does it work then?

Answer (score 1):

Since I came here from top google results, and kind of kicked of my journey to get results I want to post this here in hopes it will help someone in future.

I was trying to host my **Vue@3** app on `local IIS` to test if things work before I exchange it in production.
I am actually rewriting **Vue@2** app in **Vue@3**, and **for Vue@2** following any of these 3 links would yield success:

- https://gist.github.com/AngeloAnolin/6b19d22220b27a545e10f5fa672072fa
- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hosting-vue-js-spa-build-microsoft-iis-zainul-zain
- https://dnilvincent.com/blog/posts/host-vuejs-app-on-iis

However, in **Vue@3** this is a bit of overkill and will throw `http error 500.19 - internal server error`. Changing content of `web.config` with following content would yield success:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

That's it basically. Good luck with everything :D